# Why is this Error "line 26: Syntax Error near unexpected token 'done'?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
for (( i=1; i<= $numberstudent; i++ ))
     do
      head -n $i fullstudentsMarks | tail -n 1 > $(cut -f 2 -d ' ')
      npassed=0
      sum=0
      average=0
      for (( j=3; j<= 10; j++ ))
      do
        mark=$(cut -f $j -d ' ' $(cut -f 2 -d ' ' fullstudentsMarks))
        if ($mark>=60)
        then
         $npassed=$npassed+1
        fi
        $sum=$sum+mark
      done
      $average=$sum / $npassed
      if ($npassed==8);then
       result="successful"
      else if ($npassed>=5);then
        result="trans"
      else
       result="lost"
      fi
      idstudent=$(head -n $i fullstudentsMarks | tail -n 1 | cut -f 1 -d ' ')
      echo $idstudent+" "+$reslut+" "+$average >> resandavg
     done
```

Comment: I've focused my attention on the `else if`, which in BASH is `elif`. Just one tip to begin :)

Comment: Is this supposed to be `bash`? if so, there are many errors - you may find www.shellcheck.net helpful

Comment: @steeldriver it looks like baPHPsh :-(

Comment: yes this is Bash

Comment: Don't use $ on the left side of assignments.

Comment: As Echoes_86 hints, you are missing a `fi` in your successful/trans/lost logic. Really this has so many issues it needs a complete rewrite. `if` statements usually run the `test` command, also known as `[`, rather than starting a subshell with `(`.

Comment: Paste your code into http://www.shellcheck.net/ to see the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Please paste your script into [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).
It will give you a lot of error messages pointing to bits of the code that is not fully correct.

But you should never have ended up there. You should have tested the script a dozen times before even writing the line `$average=$sum / $npassed`.

In general when you do any sort of programming: Do not leave the testing until the very end expecting that a program will run flawlessly when you've written all of it. It's better to test your code incrementally while you write it. It's particularly easy to do with shell scripts as there is no compilation step involved.

*Nobody* writes a complete shell script with even moderately complex logic and parsing correctly on the first try (and if they do, they are probably just lucky, and surprised).

For example, you could start off with

```
for (( i = 1; i <= numberstudent; i++ )); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Does it work? Why not? Well, `numberstudent` doesn't have a value. We'll pretend it's 23.

Then add *one* new line and test again:

```
numberstudent=23
for (( i = 1; i <= numberstudent; i++ )); do
  head -n "$i" fullstudentsMarks | tail -n 1 > $(cut -f 2 -d ' ')
done
```

What happened there? Why do I get "no such file or directory" or "ambiguous redirect"? What did I even want this line to do? Well, too much was added to the script in one go, just cut it back a bit:

```
numberstudent=23
for (( i = 1; i <= numberstudent; i++ )); do
  head -n "$i" fullstudentsMarks | tail -n 1
done
```

There, now it picks the line corresponding to `$i` out of `fullstudentsMarks` and displays it. (I don't know if this is what you *actually* intended)

But oh, `numberstudent` needs to be the number of lines in the file! Ok.

```
numberstudent="$( wc -l <fullstudentsMarks )" 
for (( i = 1; i <= numberstudent; i++ )); do
  head -n "$i" fullstudentsMarks | tail -n 1
done
```

And so on, until you have a script where every line does what you want it to do and until you know it's doing it correctly (and you know it does because you tested the script after almost every single added line).